# Concat operator semantics, but with immediate subscriptions to all undrelying observables

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I want to concatenate a cold and a hot observables. That is, resulting observable should emit the result of cold observable first, then the stuff from the hot one. In the same time, I want to have subscription to the second observable, that is hot, to happen at the same time when subscription to the first one happens, otherwise I miss an important event from it.

That looks very similar to what `merge` would do. But I want to guarantee that the hot observable will not push anything before the cold one completes, which `merge` doesn't guarantee. What would be the right way around this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Replay` or `PublishLast` operators, depending upon your needs.  Each has an overload that accepts a *selector* function.

For example:

```
var coldThenHot = hot.PublishLast(cold.Concat);
```

Subscribing to `coldThenHot` causes `PublishLast` to invoke the *selector* first, creating the `Concat` query.  Then it subscribes to it and your *hot* observable.  The last value in the *hot* observable is buffered.  When the *cold* observable completes, the sequence continues with the buffered value, or simply remains silent until the last value arrives.

However, I'm curious as to what exactly you meant by *hot*.  If your *hot* observable doesn't generate a value until you subscribe, then [technically it's *cold*](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx).  If your observable is truly *hot*, then you may have already missed the value by the time this query is created.  Although, it's possible that it's implicitly buffered already (e.g., if it was created by [Observable.FromAsyncPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromasyncpattern(v=vs.103).aspx)), in which case simply concatenate the sequences like normal.

```
var coldThenHot = cold.Concat(hot);
```

Comment: Hey, that looks very interesting! I'll try your approach and reply. Regarding the *hotness* of second observable, it is actually hot (it's based on an Interval), but it emits the first item either right after subscription or after some delay. In first case, I can miss the first emitted event.

Comment: Actually, I've reread the description of Interval, and it's cold, apparently. You were right about the fact that the second observable is technically cold. Nevertheless, my needs remain the same.

Comment: Yes, `Interval` is _cold_.  If you want to `Concat` more than one value, then use `Replay` instead of `PublishLast`.  Just realize that `Replay` buffers all values indefinitely, unless you call an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.replay(v=vs.103).aspx) that accepts one or more bounding parameters; e.g., count or time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to miss previous data from the hot observable, there is the [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Subject#replaysubject) that does exactly this : as soon as you subscribe to it, it will push to the subscriber previous elements, which really looks like what you need here.

So what you have to do is subscribe to the cold observable, and when it completes (onCompleted) just subscribe to your ReplaySubject (your hot observable). You have no choice to have some buffering if you need to delay the important data of your hot observable.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually exactly what I ended up doing myself. However, I was looking for a way to do this without "leaving the monad", that is, by just combining different Rx operators, without resorting to manual subscriptions management inside. I guess, that might not be possible in given situation, but if it is, I'd like to know how.

Comment: As far as I know, this won't be feasible with the curent Rx API